# Visual Studio 2010 unit testing windows and running tests in general

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing and running my tests on VS2010 with mstest. When I want to run a test, or entire tests in a class, sometimes Visual Studio decides to run *all* my tests.

Why is that? How can I avoid it? Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it is this bug?
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524288/ctrl-r-t-runs-all-tests-the-first-time

Answer (score 1):

Might this be the same problem VS2008 seems to have, where if you use run context (Ctrl+R [Ctrl+]T) or run class (Ctrl+R [Ctrl+]C) it acts as if you used run all (Ctrl+R [Ctrl+]A) the first time after opening a solution? Or at least, it seems so to me. In VS2008 I simply stop the test run when I see this happening and restart the same operation. Then it usually works "as advertised".

No idea if and how this might be relevant to VS2010 at all at this stage...

Answer (score 0):

right click in the body of a single test and select 'run tests' should only run that test

Comment: "should" yeah i know it should.. but not would..
sometimes it is

Comment: @Chen: I agree with the "should"!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
My temporary solution at the moment is:

1. Open Test List Editor.
2. Type in your test method name in the filter box and filter it.
3. Check the tests that you want to run.
4. Right click and select "Run checked tests"

But I prefer the "should-run" as advertised if it works of course. I'm open to other better solutions.

Comment: If you can, download testdriven.net, I can't and thats why I'm stuck with this shitty test environment

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, if this applies to VS2010. In VS2008 running tests in the current context sometimes runs all tests in the solution. It seems, that context is defined by what element was last activated (usually through mouse click). If the last window selected was the code windows containing the unit test source code, then all tests in that class/file are executed. Same with selecting a (unit test-)file in the solution explorer. If however, another windows (e.g. breakpoints) was last selected, then the context is the whole solution.